# How to serialize different object level by jsonconvert

Tags: c#, json.net

I got the object below

```
public class ResponseMessage
{
 public string Code { get; set; }
 public string Msg { get; set; }
 public Person[] Data { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
 public string name { get; set; }
 public string age { get; set; }
 public PersonDetail Detail { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDetail
{
 public string Birthday { get; set; }
 public string CellPhone { get; set; }
}
```

How to generate different level by user privilege,like level 1
`{"Code":"0000","Msg":"OK"}`
,level 2
`{"Code":"0000","Msg":"OK","Data":[{"Alex","25"},{"Ben","30"}]}`

I have tried to using settings(MaxDepth),but it seems not work.....
Is there any way that can hide data dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Conditional Property Serialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm).

You have two options for implementing it:

1. If `ResponseMessage` can be modified (i.e., you can add a method to it) and if it has access to privilege level (e.g., via function call), supply a `ShouldSerialize` method.
   For example:

   ```
   public class ResponseMessage
   {
       public string Code { get; set; }
       public string Msg { get; set; }
       public Person[] Data { get; set; }

       public bool ShouldSerializeData()
       {
           // Privileger.GetPrivilege() is a naive example of a method 
           // that gets you privilige level
           return Privileger.GetPrivilege() > 1;
       }
   }
   ```
2. If not, go with a custom `ContractResolver`.
   Here's a simple one:

   ```
   public class PrivilegeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
   {
       public int privilege = -1;
       public PrivilegeContractResolver(int privilege)
       {
           this.privilege = privilege;
       }
       protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
       {
           JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
           if (property.PropertyName == "Data")
           {
               property.ShouldSerialize = dummy => privilege > 1;
           }
           return property;
       }
   }
   ```

   Example usage:

   ```
   public void Run()
   {
       ResponseMessage r = new ResponseMessage
       {
           Code = "some_code",
           Msg = "some_message",
           Data = new [] { new Person { name = "Joe" } }
       };
       var lowPriv = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r, new JsonSerializerSettings
       {
           ContractResolver = new PrivilegeContractResolver(0)
       });
       var highPriv = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r, new JsonSerializerSettings
       {
           ContractResolver = new PrivilegeContractResolver(2)
       });
       Console.WriteLine(lowPriv);  // outputs: {"Code":"some_code","Msg":"some_message"}
       Console.WriteLine(highPriv); // outputs: {"Code":"some_code","Msg":"some_message","Data":[{"name":"Joe","age":null,"Detail":null}]}
   }
   ```